# Select parent taxonomy term in Views exposed filters and get results for all its children aswell

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-exposed-filter

I've got a taxonomy vocabulary with simple terms (no parent, no child) and sometimes several terms grouped by a "fake" parent. Why fake? Because nothing is truly associated to this very parent itself.

Example:

[image]

I have a View in which I allow users to search for content associated to a term. I exposed the taxonomy filter with an autocomplete widget because there are plenty of terms. The thing is, if the user wants to get all the contents associated to all the children of a parent term, he has to write down every single child separated with a comma like: CCI BW, CCI CONNECT, CCI DE WALLONIE..... etc.

I'd like to allow him to search only for CCI and get all the results for the children. Because for now, it sends back no result.

[image]

I hope it is clear enough. If not, I'd try to do better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1317206)?

Steps:

- Open you view in the edit window.
- Goto FILTER CRITERIA and click add.
- Search for 'taxonomy'
- Select Content: Has taxonomy terms (with depth). Description in views
  should read something like

> Display content if it has the selected taxonomy terms, or children of
>   the selected terms. Due to additional complexity, this has fewer
>   options than the versions without depth.

- Choose theVocabulary for the term you want to filter for.
- Choose theSelection type for how the user should interact with this
  filter.
- Then choose your Depth this is where you tell views how many children
  to included. The current description in views reads.

> The depth will match nodes tagged with terms in the hierarchy. For
>   example, if you have the term "fruit" and a child term "apple", with a
>   depth of 1 (or higher) then filtering for the term "fruit" will get
>   nodes that are tagged with "apple" as well as "fruit". If negative,
>   the reverse is true; searching for "apple" will also pick up nodes
>   tagged with "fruit" if depth is -1 (or lower).

- Click Add
- The setting window will appear. Put a check in Expose this filter to
  visitors, to allow them to change it.
- Then Apply and save and done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I haven't played with contextual filters yet and you just made my day. That was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) module on node creation form and have the parent automatically selected when you select a child item. That way, all nodes will also have the parent term associated and will be visible through your actual view.

Comment: Ok so the only way to achieve this is updating all the existing nodes and manually check the children terms in this widget... I have almost 3k nodes already created. I guess I could develop a sort of custom module that would do the update for me...